# Why I can't use my class without parenthesis?(in C++)

Tags: c++, class, parentheses

```
//this is main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Cook.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(void){
     int l = Cook.get_life();
}

//this is cook.hpp
#ifndef HUNTER_H
#define HUNTER_H
class Cook
{
public:
    int get_life(void);
private:
    int life;
};
#endif

//this is cook.cpp
#include "Cook.hpp"
int Cook::get_life(void)
{
    life=0;
    return life;
}
```

They are all in same folder. And I get compile error when I run main.cpp. And Xcode recommended to use Cook().get_life() instead of Cook.get_life(). Can you explain why? I thought I should use Cook.get_life.

- I use Xcode.

Comment: `Cook` is the name of a class, not an object. Since `get_life()` is a non-static member, it can only be called in context of an object.  The syntax `Cook.get_life()` attempts to call the member function of an object, but `Cook` is not an object, so this is diagnosed as an error.   `Cook()` constructs an object of type `Cook`  (at least in this context), so `int l = Cook().get_life()` constructs an object of type `Cook()`, calls the `get_life()` member function of that object, and initialises `l` with the value returned.    The object of type `Cook` immediately ceases to exist.

Answer (score 1):

`get_life` is not a static function, you have to call it on an instance of your class `Cook`, and that's exactly what `Cook()` does. If you want to call `get_life` without an instance of `Cook`, you should declare your function this way :

```c
static int get_life(void);
```

And then call it like that :

```c
Cook::get_life();
```

The thing is you can't use class attributes from static member functions, so instead you need to instantiate your class `Cook` before calling your member function.

```c
Cook c = Cook(); // Cook().get_life() works to, but you don't keep your newly created object
c.get_life();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare variable with type of you class (instance) and then you can use it, But classes has `static` functions too, that mean you can use function without declare instance of it first but in that you can't use member variable of class, Reading more about concept of classes and more ...